# How to see the logs of node from putty ssh

Tags: node.js, linux, nginx, ssh, putty

By using putty, I have run the nodemon app.js and closed it, so the app is running behind.
Again if I logged in using putty, I can't see node logs and if I run the same command, it is giving error like the requesting port is already being used.

How to see the logs.

Comment: When you run the nodemon command to the background, redirect it to a file so you can see the output so something like nodemon app,js > /var/log/nodelog.log &

Comment: I am looking for exact command

Comment: There is no command available, The alternative is to redirect the output using nodejs syntax. See the following guide https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon